# Selecting from an Array in DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document that looks like this in DocumentDB

```
{
  "profile": {
    "personName": {
      "namePrefix": XXX,
      "givenName": "XXX",
      "middleName": XXX,
      "surname": "XXX",
      "nameSuffix": XXX,
      "nameTitle": XXX
    },
    "telephones": {
      "telephone": [
        {
          "telephoneType": "Home",
          "isDefault": true,
          "countryAccessCode": 1,
          "areaCityCode": XXX,
          "phoneNumber": "XXX"
        },
        {
          "telephoneType": "Work",
          "isDefault": false,
          "countryAccessCode": 1,
          "areaCityCode": XXX,
          "phoneNumber": "XXX"
        }
      ]
    },
  }
  "id": "05d236f0-2970-4f04-9785-1c62c5ddbae5"
```

I am trying to work with Azure Search and flatten my data for the index.  I would only like to include the telephone that is marked as isDefault = true.

I tried the following as well as trying ARRAY_CONTAINS but neither returned the expected results.

```
SELECT p.id, p.profile.personName.givenName, p.profile.personName.surname,   p.profile.telephones.telephone.countryAccessCode, p.profile.telephones.telephone.areaCityCode, p.profile.telephones.telephone.phoneNumber FROM Profiles p JOIN t IN p.profile.telephones.telephone WHERE t.isDefault = true
```

Comment: You may want to include what your expected results are so we can help craft the query for you.

Comment: My goal is to have a flat representation of the data, so I can use it with Azure Search.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the alias in your `JOIN` to pull out the array element.

For example:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.profile.personName.givenName,
       p.profile.personName.surname,
       t.countryAccessCode,
       t.areaCityCode,
       t.phoneNumber
FROM Profiles p
JOIN t IN p.profile.telephones.telephone
WHERE t.isDefault = true
```

Comment: I was able to get this to work, thank you so much.  I have 1 more question.  Is there a limit on the number of joins?  For example, I have 3 sets of arrays in my message and as long as I only JOIN against 2, my query works.  As soon as I add a third it blows up.

Comment: There is currently a limit of 2 JOINs. This is because DocumentDB performs a cross product which can product a lot of results. If you only need to filter (WHERE clause) on an array element without any projections (SELECT clause) - you can workaround this by using the ARRAY_CONTAINS system function.